# Finding a string after first match occurs in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a big string as

```
------%%CreationDate: 11/9/2006 1:01 PM %%BoundingBox: -1 747 53 842 %%HiResBoundingBox: -0.28---------
```

now i want to get the values after this match "%%BoundingBox:"
I mean I need to get "-1 747 53 842", so i can split it and process, please help how to do this with preg_match or with any other.
Thanks.

Comment: Does `%%BoundingBox` occur multiple times?

Comment: Does it always have `------` before and `---------` after the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
/%%BoundingBox: ([^%]*)/
```

This regex matches everything before first `%` character.

```
/%%BoundingBox: (.*?)%%/
```

This regex matches everything before `%%` - if single `%` occurs, it will be captured.

PHP code:

```
$input  = '------%%CreationDate: 11/9/2006 1:01 PM %%BoundingBox: -1 747 53 842 %%HiResBoundingBox: -0.28---------';
preg_match('/%%BoundingBox: ([^%]*)/', $input, $matches);
$output = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Does PCRE requires to escape the percentage sign? (PHP string doesn't, I just wonder a little).

Comment: @hakre Nope, in fact, this answer uses both escaped and unescaped, so assuming it was tested, it should work just fine :)

Comment: But you should not do superfluous things :D - looks better now.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the position of "%%BoundingBox:" and "%%HiResBoundingBox:" with [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php) and then extract the value with [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php).

Comment: That's typically what regular expressions would be used for :)

Comment: I know but i wanted to give an alternative. Simply to see both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the matching set is digits and spaces, so:

```
/%%BoundingBox: ([\s\d-]+)/
```

Doing so makes it work even if it's not followed by `%%`; here's an example implementation:

```
preg_match_all('/%%BoundingBox: ([\s\d-]+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1 747 53 842
)
```

You could make it more strict by enforcing 4 sets of numbers:

```
preg_match_all('/%%BoundingBox: ((?:\s*\-?\d+){4})/', $string, $matches);
```

**Update**

To parse them into key-value pairs, you can do this:

```
preg_match_all('/%%([^:]++):([^%]*+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], array_map('trim', $matches[2])));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [CreationDate] => 11/9/2006 1:01 PM
    [BoundingBox] => -1 747 53 842
    [HiResBoundingBox] => -0.28---------
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '------%%CreationDate: 11/9/2006 1:01 PM %%BoundingBox: -1 747 53 842 %%HiResBoundingBox: -0.28---------';
$pattern = "#(%%BoundingBox: )(.*?)( %%HiResBoundingBox)#i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[2]);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1 747 53 842
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$str='------%%CreationDate: 11/9/2006 1:01 PM %%BoundingBox: -1 747 53 842 %%HiResBoundingBox: -0.28---------';;
preg_match("/\%\%BoundingBox:\s(.*)\s\%\%/",$str,$match);
```

**Will give**

```
Array ( [0] => %%BoundingBox: -1 747 53 842 %% [1] => -1 747 53 842 )
```

Then you can find your value by

```
echo $match[1];// -1 747 53 842
```

Comment: If there was another `%%` in the string, this would fail.